How to reference path, given that I want to include an image in HTML file that resides on a different drive than my HTML document?
Here's the problem:
HTML Document Location- G:\html files\projects\htmlforms\index.html
Image Location- D:\resources\images\stock images\logo.jpg
Is this some folder permission problem ?
I've tried- <img src="file:///D:/resources/images/stock images/logo.jpg" alt="image">
I am just expecting an simple image to be display

is this answer your question?

If the HTML file is opened in the browser as file:///G:/html files/projects/htmlforms/index.html then it should just work (I just tried). However if you open the HTML file through a local web server using something like http://localhost/ .. .. .. /index.html then the browser will block everything that uses a file: URL for security reasons. You simply can not use file: from a page hosted on a web server.

I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS myself, but from what I know, the image has to be in the same folder and have the .html in the image's file name. It should be relatively simple to move the image's location, so no need to stress there. It will also help to shorten the image's link. Here's an example tag:
<(img src="cvpfp.html.jpeg" alt="Profile Picture">
(Please don't include the parentheses in the tag, that just helps it show up on stack overflow)
In this case, I had emailed the image to myself from my phone and downloaded it.
my source consists of the file name, the document type, and the image type.
I really hope this helps! Please let me know if I can clarify anything or answer any other questions.

Image doesn't need to be in same folder. It doesn't need to follow any particular naming style.
And for your example tag. please wrap in code block to make it nicer if you want. I don't see any purpose of the bracket you used.

from what I know, the image has to be in the same folder and have the .html in the image's file name - Both incorrect. It can be in any folder, although for more serious projects it is common or best practice that they reside in / under / close to the folder(s) where HTML, JS and CSS are located. Also, there are no rules whatsoever for the image file name.
